# Byte Array to Image using C# in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been searching for the past few days but did not manage to find a solution for my problem. I am currently working on a xamarin Android app. I want to display an image by using the byte array column from by database. I am using another program to find the byte array of a specific photo and after that I insert manually its value in the byte array column from my principal project.

This is my code where I am trying to reproduce the image:

```
Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(currentexercis.image, 0, currentexercis.image.Length);
viewHolder.exercis_photo.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Currentexercis.image represents the byte array from my database, and its value seems to be OK, however every time bitmap is null.

This is the code from my other program where I convert the image into bytearray:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(opendlg.FileName);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
dbpicEntities1 db = new dbpicEntities1();
db.MyPictures.Add(new MyPicture() { FileName=fileName, Data = ms.ToArray() });
db.SaveChanges();
MessageBox.Show("success");
```

Comment: In the Java API, `decodeByteArray` returns `null` if the image could not be decoded. I assume the same thing happens in the Xamarin library.

Comment: Thanks, Ted, but since I get the byte array from another program it should be converted back to image with no problem. It`s just the reverse process.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the four-argument version of `DecodeByteArray` and pass in options that tell the factory how to decode your particular image.

Comment: I have just added a new button to that secondary program in order to see if the byte array can be used for decode and the image seems to be created , but I am using memory stream in that program and in the android program I cannot use memory stream since my image is of type Android.Widget Image view and the image created with memorystream is of type System Drawing Core Image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use like this.

```
byte [] imageArray // is your data
MemoryStream mStream = new MemorySteram ();
mStream.write(imageArray,0,imageArray.Length);
Image img = Image.FromStream(mStream);
img.save(filelocation);

Bitmap bitmapimg = BitmapFactory.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(mStream); 
// if you want to use Bitmap
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, when I am trying to complete the last line regarding bitmap creating, I need to choose between System Drawing Core and Android Graphics. I have to use Android Graphics, and it seems that it does not have a constructor for Bitmap...

Comment: following article link,I think you will find it how to use bitmap.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899497/create-image-file-from-byte-array-in-documents-xamarin-android)

Answer (score 0):

> Byte Array to Image using C# in Xamarin

There are some third-party library which implements this feature quite well like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glide.Xamarin/).

For `Glide`, there is official document shows how to use it in `Xamarin.Android` project: [Binding a .JAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/). 
Or you could directly use it from the nuget package:

[image]

Then you can code for example like this:

```
Glide.With(context)
     .Load(imageBytes)
     .Apply(RequestOptions.CircleCropTransform())
     .Into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

convert to byteArray

```
 byte[] imgdata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathToImage);
```

convert byte array to bitmap

```
 private void OnGetMemberAvatarCompleted(byte[] avatarBytes)
{
   var avatarImageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.memberProfile_avatar);
   if (avatarImageView != null)
   {
      var imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(avatarBytes, 0,avatarBytes.Length);
      RunOnUiThread(() => avatarImageView.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap));
   }
}
```